# ORDS response from POST service after insert

Tags: sql, oracle, api, plsql, oracle11g

I am currently facing a hard choice:

- On one hand, if I use AutoREST, I can easily get POST response. However, I cannot customise the API behaviour as I wanted, such as case-insentsitive query.

  - I enabled the AutoREST with Table object.   I am aware that I can use `?q={}` to do the query.
  - However I cannot query the data with case insensitive.
  - For example, `?q={"name":"Chang"}` but I would like to find all date with name chang, without considering letter case.
  - I know I can define a customized handler to do this and do query as `?name=chang`.   But if currently I did `ords.enable_object`, is there anyway to customize this on top of it?
- On the other hand, if I define every services I need, I am having trouble with getting proper POST response.

  - I am trying to implement the POST service and return certain values after insert (i.e., output some values to POST’s response). I have tried several ways but no luck.
  - I have tried declaring local variables but they are not returned. I have also tried select after insert. Not working as well. I have a procedure called `insert_customer`, where there are several `IN` parameters and a `OUT` parameter as `customer_id`. But the `customer_id` just cannot be outputed.

Here is am example I have:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE insert_customer (
   p_corporate_key  IN  customers.corporate_key%TYPE,
   p_fullname       IN  customers.fullname%TYPE,
   p_email          IN  customers.email%TYPE,
   p_phone          IN  customers.phone%TYPE,
   p_job_title      IN  customers.job_title%TYPE,
   p_department     IN  customers.department%TYPE,
   p_organization   IN  customers.organization%TYPE,
   p_customer_id    OUT customers.customer_id%TYPE
)
AS
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO customers (corporate_key, fullname, email, phone, job_title, department, organization)
   VALUES (p_corporate_key, p_fullname, p_email, p_phone, p_job_title, p_department, p_organization)
   RETURN customer_id INTO p_customer_id;
EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS
   THEN HTP.print(SQLERRM);
END;
/

BEGIN
   ORDS.DEFINE_SERVICE(
      p_module_name => 'insert.customers' ,
      p_base_path   => '/customers/',
      p_method      => 'POST',
      p_source      => ‘DECLARE
                           l_customer_id number;
                        BEGIN
                           insert_customer(p_corporate_key => :corporate_key,
                              p_fullname      => :fullname,
                              p_email         => :email,
                              p_phone         => :phone,
                              p_job_title     => :job_title,
                              p_department    => :department,
                              p_organization  => :organization
                              p_customer_id  => :l_customer_id);
                        END;'
   );

   COMMIT;
END;
```

`customer_id` is a incremental sequence generated by trigger.

I would like to insert a customer (with relevant information) and then return the `customer_id`.

---

**EDIT:**

I have checked the procedure `insert_customer` individually, and it is working fine.

```
SQL>variable l_id number;
SQL>exec insert_customer('a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', :l_id);

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> print l_id

      L_ID
----------
       102
```

And I have also added

```
htp.prn(:corporate_key);
htp.prn(:l_customer_id);
```

or

```
htp.prn(:corporate_key);
htp.prn(l_customer_id);
```

after execution of `insert_customer` in the `p_source`, before `END`.

However, only `corporate_key` is printed out, no `l_customer_id`.

So I am wondering, the procedure outputting value to OUT parameter, individually, BUT not within the `p_source` of ORDS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I have solved my issue.

The problem is from this part of code:

```
BEGIN
   ORDS.DEFINE_SERVICE(
      p_module_name => 'insert.customers' ,
      p_base_path   => '/customers/',
      p_method      => 'POST',
      p_source      => ‘DECLARE
                           l_customer_id number;
                        BEGIN
                           insert_customer(p_corporate_key => :corporate_key,
                              p_fullname      => :fullname,
                              p_email         => :email,
                              p_phone         => :phone,
                              p_job_title     => :job_title,
                              p_department    => :department,
                              p_organization  => :organization
                              p_customer_id   => :l_customer_id);
                        END;'
   );

   COMMIT;
END;
```

At this line: `p_customer_id   => :l_customer_id`.

Because variable prefixed with `:` is regarded as variable from outside of `p_source`, such as `:corporate_key` and `:fullname`, however, `l_customer_id` here is declared within `p_source`. So, what I need to do is just remove the `:` in front of it and print it out using `htp.prn`, as the follows:

```
BEGIN
   ORDS.DEFINE_SERVICE(
      p_module_name => 'insert.customers' ,
      p_base_path   => '/customers/',
      p_method      => 'POST',
      p_source      => ‘DECLARE
                           l_customer_id number;
                        BEGIN
                           insert_customer(p_corporate_key => :corporate_key,
                              p_fullname      => :fullname,
                              p_email         => :email,
                              p_phone         => :phone,
                              p_job_title     => :job_title,
                              p_department    => :department,
                              p_organization  => :organization
                              p_customer_id   => l_customer_id);
                           htp.prn(''{"customer_id":"''||l_customer_id||''"}'');
                        END;'
   );

   COMMIT;
END;
```

The request and response:

```
POST /api/schema/customers/ HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: xxx
Content-Type: application/json
Host: url:port
User-Agent: HTTPie/0.9.4

{
    "corporate_key": "a",
    "department": "a",
    "email": "a",
    "fullname": "a",
    "job_title": "a",
    "organization": "a",
    "phone": "a"
}

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Thu, 09 Mar 2017 15:46:49 GMT
Server: Jetty(9.2.z-SNAPSHOT)
Transfer-Encoding: chunked    

{
    "customer_id": "130"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe someone else will add a better solution, but for now I will share with you what we have been using for quite a while and it works just fine.

Since this is being returned over HTTP, we use the [htp](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28280_01/portal.1111/e12042/pshtp.htm#YPREF266) package. Particularly `prn` procedure.

```
l_response        := <your returned value>;
htp.prn(l_response);
```

One caveat here, `htp.prn` accepts only up to 32K string length. Therefor, if you are returning longer than that (e.g. CLOB), you need to do it through a loop

For example, we call the loop procedure at the end of the block/procedure:

```
proc_send_clob_response(l_response);
```

where proc_send_clob_response definition is as follows:

```
PROCEDURE proc_send_clob_response(
                                  i_rest_response IN CLOB
                                 )
AS
  l_response_body_clob  CLOB;
  l_response_length     NUMBER;
  l_response_buffer     VARCHAR2(32767);
  l_response_chunk_size BINARY_INTEGER := 32000;
  l_offset              INTEGER := 1;

BEGIN
    l_response_body_clob := i_rest_response;
    dbms_lob.open(l_response_body_clob, dbms_lob.lob_readonly); 
    l_response_length := dbms_lob.getlength (l_response_body_clob);

    WHILE (l_response_length > 0)
    LOOP
          dbms_lob.read(l_response_body_clob, l_response_chunk_size, l_offset, l_response_buffer);

         htp.prn(l_response_buffer);

         /* Increase Counter */
         l_offset := l_offset + l_response_chunk_size;

         /* Resize CLOB length */
         l_response_length := l_response_length - l_response_chunk_size;

    END LOOP;

    dbms_lob.close(l_response_body_clob); 
EXCEPTION 
WHEN OTHERS THEN
   --your exception handling here
END;
```

Notice that we use `htp.prn` and not `htp.p` as `htp.p` will add newline `\n` at the end, which we do not desire when we contactentat the output in the loop.

Comment: I have tried your way. But still not working. Please see the EDIT part of my question. Thanks!